# Parent ID not updating on Attachment

Tags: apex, controller, list, attachment, merge

I have a requirment where when 2 records are merged, the attachment related to merged record should be inserted to parent/master record.
Below is my code related to this

```
List<Attachment> attObj = [SELECT body, bodylength, contenttype, description, isprivate, name, ownerid FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = :id2];
            List<Attachment> newAttObj = new List<Attachment>();
            // Loop through the list and update the Name field
            for (Attachment a : attObj) {
                Attachment ax = new Attachment();
                ax.Body = a.Body;
                ax.contenttype = a.contenttype;
                ax.description = a.description;
                ax.isprivate = a.isprivate;
                ax.ParentId = id1;
                ax.name = a.name;
                ax.ownerid = a.ownerid;
                newAttObj.add(ax);
            }
            //Update the database
            insert newAttObj;
```

here id2 is the merged record and id1 is the master record.

So now, the issue here is that the attachment is not getting inserted to parent/master record after the merge. Even when I hardcode the id as ax.ParentId = '16 digit ID', the record is not getting inserted to parent record.

**_________________________________________________________________**

**Update**:

After learning that attachments are depricated, I have updated my code as follows

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> newAttObj = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
            
            list<ContentDocumentLink> contdoclink = [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId,Visibility, IsDeleted, ShareType,ContentDocument.Title,ContentDocument.createdDate, ContentDocument.FileType FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId =:id2];
           
            // Loop through the list and update the Name field
            for (ContentDocumentLink a : contdoclink) {
                ContentDocumentLink ax = new ContentDocumentLink();
                ax.ContentDocumentId = a.ContentDocumentId;
                ax.Visibility = a.Visibility;
                ax.ShareType = a.ShareType;
                ax.ContentDocument.Title = a.ContentDocument.Title;
                ax.LinkedEntityId = id1;
               // ax.ContentDocument.FileType = a.ContentDocument.FileType;
                //ax.ownerid = a.ownerid;
                newAttObj.add(ax);
            }
            //Update the database
            insert newAttObj;
```

Even now, the attachment of merged record is not getting updated with ParentID of master record

Can anyone please let me know if i missed anything here?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using content documents? Attachments I believe are deprecated..

Comment: @gNerb Updated my code with the given suggestion. Please suggest

Comment: If you're using `Database.merge` method, then all child objects are automatically reparented to the master, so you don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: @DavidCheng doesn't the merge method only work on accounts leads and contacts?

Comment: @SK_112 I don't think the provided code is enough for us to troubleshoot, can you include a larger code sample in your question.

Comment: @gNerb you're right I found [other documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm) that states only account / contact / lead can be merged.  The database.merge doc is inconsistent and misleading, then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @gNerb for suggesting to use content documents instead of attachments as they are depricated in lightning.

Here is my final solution:

```
   List<ContentVersion> attObj = [SELECT Title,PathOnClient,VersionData,FirstPublishLocationId   
           FROM ContentVersion WHERE FirstPublishLocationId =:id2];
   List<ContentVersion> newAttObj = new List<ContentVersion>();
   // Loop through the list and update the Name field
   for (ContentVersion a : attObj) {
       ContentVersion objCntNote = new ContentVersion();
       objCntNote.Title = a.Title;
       objCntNote.PathOnClient = a.PathOnClient;
       objCntNote.VersionData = a.VersionData;
       objCntNote.FirstPublishLocationId = id1;
       newAttObj.add(objCntNote);
}
   //Update the database
   insert newAttObj;
```

I hope this helps someone who is stuck with similar kind of issue